# AWS Secrets Manager rotation for RDS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kms

It's my understanding that Secrets Manager can automatically rotate the password for an RDS database. When this occurs, is there a race condition for long running processes using the old secret?

I can't find documentation describing this race condition, but I would imagine a process running right before key rotation and using the old secret wouldn't be able to hit the database until it re-fetches the newest secret. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments in [Rotate Amazon RDS database credentials automatically with AWS Secrets Manager | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/rotate-amazon-rds-database-credentials-automatically-with-aws-secrets-manager/), on RDS and secrets rotation:

> Databases authenticate when a connection is established. As a result, open connections are not impacted by rotations performed by Secrets Manager.

So, your process for connecting to RDS should always be:

1. get secrets from Secret Manager
2. create DB connection

I suppose there is a tiny window there between 1 and 2, so for reliability you might want to write this with an exception/error handler so that it can re-fetch the secrets and retry the connection one time if you see a transient authentication failure.